# Are there any tools to re-namespace a Java library and its references?

Tags: java

This must be quite a common problem. An application depends on Library A and Library B. Library A depends on Library C-v1 (version 1 of Library C) and Library B depends on some newly introduced features in Library C-v2 (version 2 of Library C). And of course, there was some major refactoring in Library C-v2 which means it can't be backwards compatible with Library C-v1. But Library C-v1 and Library C-v2 have the same package names and class names.

Now, it should be possible to effectively "re-namespace" Library C-v1. For example, a class called com.example.MyClass could be re-namespaced to old.com.example.MyClass. It should be completely possible to build an automated tool that takes a binary JAR and changes all the package names in this fashion.

It should also be possible to change the references in a dependent library. For example, any reference in Library A to Library C should be changed to point to the new package names.

Surely there must already be a tool available to do this?

(PS: I'm sure some clever person will mention OSGi, but I want to do this as a one-time activity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jarjar](https://github.com/shevek/jarjar) does what you are asking:

> You can avoid problems where your library depends on a specific version of a library, which may conflict with the dependencies of another library.

The libraries are repackaged into your jar and renamed in the process. It also includes an Ant-Task.

Comment: Thanks - jarjar actually solved my problem for this. But my company wasn't happy with using binary assembly tools for production code, so we used a different solution - replacing "Library A" with a bespoke solution which is compatible with "Library C-v2". But I think jarjar is a very cool utility!!

Answer (score 1):

Try the `maven-shade-plugin`. It will change packages you specify: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html

Answer (score 0):

No, what you're talking about is major surgery, not a cosmetic renaming.  There's no tool to help do this except for an IDE and lots of hard thinking.

You can't expect any warranty or certification of correct behavior to hold if those libraries are from a 3rd party.

I agree that it's a problem (e.g. the conflicts between Spring and Hibernate dependencies), but your solution isn't the way to go.  This is what OSGi was born for.

Answer (score 0):

If you had the source code, you could create an Ant task to do the refactoring, then reJar the old library.